# Find closest vector

Tags: algorithm, search

We have a list of vectors with dimensions greater than two(dimension can be 10, 32, 64 or 15) and an arbitrary vector as the input.

It is required to find from the list of vectors the closest to the input vector

(for example: 10000 and 10001 are close vectors, but 10111 and 10000 are not close vectors), but without complete passage through the list. I know several Nearest neighbor search algorithms that allow us to find the closest similar element: kd-trees, Voronoi diagram , but they are aimed at finding elements in a plane or in 3-dimensional space.

Are there  any algorithms, which  allow to find the nearest vector, which dimension greater then 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all index structures for [nearest-neighbour search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) support multi-dimensional data.

For example [KD-Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) and [R-Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) are well suited for low dimensional data ( d < 5-10). When the number of dimensions increases you run into the [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) and most index structures degenerate (they become less selective).

Beyond something like 20 dimensions (this is just a rule of thumb and highly data distribution dependent) these traditional index structures offer no benefit  over a full scan over the data. Then you can either

- try to optimize this scan (e.g., early stopping during distance calculation or [VA-File](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.40.480&rep=rep1&type=pdf))
- use approximate nearest neighbour approaches (e.g., [locality sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing)) that are fast but do not guarantee to return the nearest neighbour (but usually a close one)